# How can I have a pre-build event halt the build if something went wrong with it (VS 2010/C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm executing a simple console exe program in a pre build event that consolidates a bunch of xml files into one big xml file. This will vastly cut down on spin-up time when the program is run.

Is there a special return code I can use that will inform VS-2010 that something went wrong with the pre-build event and will cause the build to halt?

Is there some other solution to this?

Thanks,

Isaac

Comment: why do not use PostBuild event ? I dont't think all these files you need in order to be able to build them...

Comment: I don't think I can do it, because the file that gets built needs to be embedded into the dll

Comment: I think the PRE-build event is called so, cause it's executed before actually build starts, so event if we find out the way to recover from VS success/fail, it shouldn't resolve your problem, as all that XML files are already processed. Isn't it?

Comment: However, no, I do need to do this pre-build, and there are some things that might happen that will cause this pre-build to fail (ex. certain files not existing..). If the pre-build fails then I could have a bad, buggy build of my library project coming out. I don't want that.

Comment: Pre build event executed before build. So if you process all yuor XML data in PRE-build, they will ALWAYS be processed before VS begin to build, so there is no way you can now if build WILL succeed at the moment of prebuild, as build comes after prebuild finished.

Comment: That's true, I don't know if the build will succeed or not. But if the pre-build fails, I do not want to bother building. That way whoever is trying to build will have to fix the problem that is breaking the pre-build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build events normally abort when one of their commands fail.  If you have to such condition then you can create one with the exit /b command.  Like this:

```
if exist "foo.bar" goto good
exit /b 42
:good
```

The exit code is fairly arbitrary, anything other than 0 causes a build abort.